# Why can't I create a std::map with this struct as value

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, dictionary, struct, typedef

I have the following struct.

```
struct ShaderObject
{
    const GLchar* File;
    ShaderType Type;
    GLuint Shader;
    ShaderObject(const GLchar* File, ShaderType Type);
};
```

And this type of map.

```
typedef map<string, ShaderObject> Shaders;
```

The compiler gives me an error, linking to the implementation of `map`.

```
 Error 1 error C2512: 'ShaderObject::ShaderObject': No appropriate default constructor
 available c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\map 198 1
```

**I don't understand the error. How can I fix it?** Because I never had an error like this before and I can't explain, I am not sure which informations you will need. Please feel free to ask for details! **Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide a default constructor (a constructor that can be called with no arguments) for `ShaderObject` if you want to put it inside `std::map`. The reason for this is, if you use `operator[]` on `map` for a key that doesn't exist, it will automatically insert that key and a **new** `ShaderObject` as the value. It will use the default constructor to create this object.

Comment: You don't *have to* provide a default constructor, you just need to stay away from all member functions that require the mapped type to be default constructible, such as `operator[]`. You can call the `map::at` member function instead.

Comment: @anio, a "no arg constructor" is usually called a default constructor. Using the conventional name helps everyone understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was looking for the error more than two hours and you got me the answer.